Electric skateboard: helmet replacement
My 14 yr old son has an electric skateboard. Yesterday he came off it and banged his head slightly but enough to mark the back of the helmet slightly. Today however, he had a BAD fall which resulted in a tumble and banged the back of helmet then rolled and banged front as well as, scraping the side, causing some deeper scratches on helmet.... As well as elbows, shoulder blades, bum bone, etc etc . I'm presuming this means a new helmet is required? But just curious, after the fall yesterday, should I have replaced it then? Is there a rule of thumb, so to speak, as to when you should replace if in a fall, if helmet makes contact with ground? After 1 fall, 2? Any advice would be appreciated. Obviously I want my son to be safe and will replace this one, as I'm sure that's what is needed after today, but maybe I can learn more with the help from others,like yourselves. Thanks in advance.

Replace a helmet that has done its job - they are single use items.
In an impact, the EPS foam (polystychrene/polystyrene) expanded foam will be squashed.  That's its purpose, to slow down a collision and make it take longer.  This directly translates to a lower peak impact.
Once the foam has been squashed once, it will be unable to offer the same level of delay in a later impact.
If an ambulance was called, then the helmet may be broken apart to gauge the level of impact and injury, so will be unusable.

The outer plastic shell of the helmet exists for three main reasons.

Abrasion protection during normal handling   If the foam flakes off, the helmet becomes thinner and therefore less able to do its job
Water resistance a foam that is waterlogged by riding in rain is not going to compress as well as dry foam in an accident
Sliding the plastic shell prevents the foam from digging into the road surface and providing a rotational torque to the head during an accident.


ANSWER it is a judgement call that you as a parent have to make on behalf of your skateboarder and noone on the internet can give you a definitive answer.
If the helmet can't do the job any more, then definitely replace it.
If the helmet appears functionally fine but has scratches; that's up to you to make the judgement call.
If the helmet is just dirty, it's probably okay to clean with water and keep using.

This is a fuzzy grey area, but consider your son has crashed twice in two days.   He'll probably need a helmet again in the future.
Is he pushing his limits/current skills too far?  Can you suggest he tries a skateboard park rather than footpaths/sidewalks?   A different environment might help.

As a skateboarder, I agree with this.  It's hard to judge (especially from just text), but scratches are pretty normal on helmets.  If you ever get a crack though (however small), I'd say replace.  The cost of a new helmet is not nothing, but is certainly relatively low, especially compared to the potential to any head injuries.

@BruceWayne yeah there's no hard-and-fast demarcation between "still okay" and replace.  Instead its all about personal risk acceptance.   It also relates to where the rider goes - bootling around a skate park is a different risk profile to riding the skateboard on the road with traffic.

Might be worth adding that if it's a helmet with mips then the "mips" bit is probably done

@SamDean that's an excellent point - I can't really speak to MIPS so do feel free to add another answer expanding on that point specifically.

I can't currently find a source either way for whether MIPS is "done" after one crash. I've often heard in skiing and cycling circles that it is true but I don't think this anecdotal evidence is worth an answer of it's own. I will update if I find a source.

@SamDean that's worth being a question of it's own then.

@Criggie I REPLACED THE HELMET IMMEDIATELY. BEST SAFE, THAN SORRY, AS THEY SAY. ALSO, YES, HE'S PUSHING LIMITS FOR HIS SKILL LEVEL, DEFINITELY! HE IS AUTISTIC (HIGH FUNCTIONING) & ALTHOUGH FAIRGROUND RIDES ETC, SCARE HIM (HE FAINTED THE 1ST/ONLY TIME ON ONE) I FEEL HE'S SENSORY SEEKING ON THE BOARD (A TRAIT). HE'S NOT FALLEN SINCE, I THINK IT SCARED HIM ENOUGH TO REALISE ACCIDENTS CAN HAPPEN WITHOUT WARNING. I'M HOPING TO FIND A CLUB TO GO, TO LEARN/EXPLORE SKILLS BUT ASD SOCIAL DIFFICULTIES, MAKE THIS HARD. ANYWAY, THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP, ADVICE & KNOWLEDGE, IT'S GREATLY APPRECIATED.

@SamDean, THANK YOU FOR YOUR INPUT AND KNOWLEDGE. I WILL B3 HONEST AND SAY, I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT MIPS IS, IF THIS IS CARELESS OF ME AS A PARENT FOR NOT KNOWING THEN I'LL ADMIT I'VE BEEN NAIVE BUT WILLING TO LEARN TO KEEP MY SON SAFE. I'LL BE SURE TO RESEARCH MIPS NOW. THANK YOU SO MUCH.
